# Firestore persistence latency

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I tend to observe random latency between when an entry is stored in Firestore, and when that entry is queryable through Firestore API. Most of the times it is instant, but can be up to a couple of days in the worst case.

To be specific, data upload is from a mobile phone, and querying is done from a (separate) desktop.

Is there any SLO on when a stored entry becomes queryable?

Answer (score 0):

There is no SLO, mostly because Firestore is currently in beta.  Though I find it extremely unlikely that anything would take two days to become visible to another client.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore offers strong consistency. A transaction that has been committed will be immediately available.

Most likely your data changes are not being applied correctly from the mobile phone.